# where to change the terms and conditions in the checkout page of WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently using the Mystile theme and was wondering which file will allow me to change the contents of the terms and conditions. It is currently just a link to the home page. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a page, something like "Term", Fill your term here.

Then,from Woocommerce menu -> setting -> Pages -> Term Page ID, select you "Term" page that you have created before.

Comment: This is now under "Woocommerce -> Settings -> Checkout"